# Opening blank page after asking permissions when i run the app.But when i debug everything is working fine. Why is that

Tags: android, zxing

Hi My app flow is app should ask camera and storage permissions and immediately it should open QrScan camera. When i debug every thing is working fine but when i run the app a blank page is opening after asking permission , why is that can any one please explain.

Am using ZXing scanner view .

```
public static boolean checkAndRequestPermissions(final Activity context) {
    int ExtstorePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( context,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE );
    int cameraPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( context,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA );
    List <String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList <>();
    if (cameraPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add( Manifest.permission.CAMERA );
    }
    if (ExtstorePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded
                .add( Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE );
    }
    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( context, listPermissionsNeeded
                        .toArray( new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()] ),
                REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS );
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS:
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Requires acces to Camera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                // initAds();
                finish();
            } else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Requires Storage Permissions.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                finish();
            } else {

            }
            break;
    }

}
```

This is the Code for permissions. and following is the code for scanning

```
private void ScanQrcode() {
zXingScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
zXingScannerView.setResultHandler((ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler)context);
zXingScannerView.startCamera();
setContentView( zXingScannerView );

}
```

Manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />
```

Opening blank page after asking permissions instead of scan camera when i run the app and if i change the mode of phone means from potraite to landscape then scan camera is opening.. But when i debug everything is working fine no need to turn the phone.

Comment: Try Switching `setContentView` and `startCamera()` lines ..

Comment: Tried But not working.

Comment: Okay then .. check for logs .. there must be some error during opening camera ..

Comment: Logcat is not showin any error. My my doubt is if there is an error when i debug also it should show blank page right? But scan camera is opening smoothly when i debug. Why is that Please Tell me.

Comment: Put some delay with handler on startCamera method then it will work ..

Comment: . Sorry am fresher in android. delay means

Comment: what is calling checkAndRequestPermissions?  Specifcally, what happens when it returns false?  My guess is that ActivityCompat.requestPermissions is async so checkandRequestPermisisons is returning false and your QrScan camera never has a chance to open.  Try removing the 'return false' from checkAndRequestPermisisons and see if that works.

Comment: final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed( new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                zXingScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(MainActivity.this);
                zXingScannerView.setResultHandler((ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler)context);
                setContentView( zXingScannerView );
                zXingScannerView.startCamera();
            }
        } ,100);    added this way but not working

Comment: @Robert Conley Yes removed return false , But not Working. But in that case when i debug also the same issue will araise right? But when i debug camera is opening .

Comment: @Manu, I thought it could have been a case when in debug mode, the app wasn't asking for permissions and in release mode it was.

Comment: @Robert Conley No App is asking permissions in debug mode also i have checked

Comment: Please somebody give me some solution for this.

Comment: Some where in the middle of logcat i can see this But this is coming only for the first time the app is inatalledE/CameraService: Permission Denial: can't use the camera pid=23496, uid=10232
.2019-06-12 01:47:20.584 23496-23850/app.appname W/CameraBase: An error occurred while connecting to camera 0: Status(-8): '1: validateClientPermissionsLocked:931: Caller "app.explico.sg" (PID 10232, UID 23496) cannot open camera "0" without camera permission'.    Can anyone tell me how to resolve this